# how do you make something loop a specific amount of times in python?

Tags: python

hello I am trying to make a warhammer 40k dice roller and I made this code however it does not roll the right amount of dice I would appreceate help on how to make it work

```py
import  random
count = 0

dice_to_roll=input("how many dice are you rolling? ")
hit = input("what do you hit on? ")
print("rolling dice!!!!!!")

while str(count) < dice_to_roll:
    die = random.randint(1, 6)
    count = count + 1
    if str(die) >= hit:
        print(die)
    else:
        print("done")
```

Comment: Hint: use numbers, not strings.

Comment: Try ‘range’ or ‘enumerate’. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

`input` is returning a string. Making the other one a string and checking equality is comparing the lengths of the string, not the values. To make yours work, use `int(input(...))` and remove the `str()` casts that you're doing.

Comment: It would actually check lexicographical order, not length. (So weirdly enough, it sort of works for two 'number' strings, as long as they're the same number of digits, which can make the problem harder to notice for beginners.)

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import random
dice_to_roll = int(input("how many dice are you rolling? "))
hit = int(input("what do you hit on? "))
print ("rolling dice!!!!!!")

for i in range(dice_to_roll):
    die = random.randint(1,6)
    if die>=hit:
        print(f"dice result:{die},hit:{hit},hit success!")
    else:
        print(f"dice result:{die},hit:{hit},hit failed!")
print("done")
```

Result:

```
how many dice are you rolling? 1
what do you hit on? 3
rolling dice!!!!!!
dice result:6,hit:3,hit success!
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting your `count` to a string try and convert your input `dice_to_roll` to an int.